# What are the roots of this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, roots, quadratics

I have a quadratic equation $ ax^2 +bx+c =0 $, where $ a,b,c $ all are positives and are in Arithmetic Progression.

Also, the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers.

I need to find out $ \alpha + \beta + \alpha\beta $.

I have tried taking $ a = a' - d , b = a' , c = a' + d $ because I have supposed $ a' $ is the first term and $ d $ is common difference, I used sum of roots and product of roots rule, but nothing helped..

Comment: What are $\alpha$ and $\beta$? What are you doing when you take $a= a'-d$, etc?

Comment: If the roots (assumed $\alpha, \beta$) are integers, you can divide through by $a$ to get an equation with $a=1$ because you have $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$ as a monic polynomial with integer coefficients and the same roots.

Comment: See @MikePierce

Comment: What exactly are you looking for as your answer?

Comment: See, I edited @S.Ong

Comment: Probably using Vieta`s theorem with $a+c=2b$ will help. And you get $\frac{b}{a}-1$ and still we haven't used the given that the roots are integers. It may be helpful to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that the equation $$ax^2+(a+d)x+a+2d=0$$
has integer roots, which says $1+\frac{d}{a}\in\mathbb Z$.

Let $\frac{d}{a}=k$.

Hence, we have $$x^2+(1+k)x+1+2k=0$$
has integer roots, which gives
$$(1+k)^2-4(1+2k)=n^2,$$ where $n$ is non-negative integer number,
which gives
$$k^2-6k-3=n^2$$ or
$$(k-3)^2=n^2+12$$ or
$$(k-3-n)(k-3+n)=12$$ and the rest is smooth:

Since $n$ is non-negative integer, we obtain two cases only.

1. $n-k+3=6$ and $n+k-3=-2$, which gives $k=-1$;
2. $n-k+3=-2$ and $n+k-3=6$, which gives $k=7$.

Comment: Why $ 1+ \frac{d}{a} $ ?

Comment: @Ravi Prakash Because $ax^2+(a+d)x+a+2d=0\Leftrightarrow  x^2+\left(1+\frac{d}{a}\right)x+1+\frac{2d}{a}=0$ and since $\alpha+\beta=-\left(1+\frac{d}{a}\right)\in\mathbb Z$, we obtain $\frac{d}{a}\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

If the roots are integers, we can write $x^2 + bx + c = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$. Note that it's okay to take $a=1$, since $b-a = c-b \implies \frac{b-a}{a} = \frac{c-b}{a}$, i.e. the arithmetic progression is preserved.

Now write $c = b + (b-1) = 2b-1$.

Use Vieta's: $\alpha + \beta = -b$ and $\alpha\beta  = 2b-1$.

$\alpha = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 - 8b +4}}{2}$. But $\alpha$ is an integer, so $(b-4)^2 -12$ is a perfect square means that we must have $b = 8$ (can be checked manually by trying squares up to 6, since difference between consecutive squares is $2n+1$). Then $\alpha + \beta + \alpha\beta = -b + (2b-1) = b - 1 = 7$.

Comment: But answer is 7

Comment: My bad, had a brain fart there.

Comment: Note that $(b-4)^2-12=d^2$ is equivalent to $e^2-12=d^2$ or $e^2-d^2=(e+d)(e-d)=12$ and for integers one is looking for two factors of $12$ which have the same parity $2\times 6$ will do. Now $b\gt 0$ picks out the solution you need. This technique (rather than "check manually") works in other situations where a manual check might be tedious or impracticable.